# PHP How to delete a specific line in a text file using user input?

Tags: php, html

A user selects a number "$Num = $_POST['Number']" from a drop down to delete a line from a text file.
Ex.

Cat
Dog
Mouse

Lets say they chose line 3. How do I delete the line in the file so it just prints:

Cat
Dog

using only the number they chose and not the actual words in the line?

Comment: Give us what you wrote

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
$row_number = 0;    // Number of the line we are deleting
$file_out = file("file.txt"); // Read the whole file into an array

//Delete the recorded line
unset($file_out[$row_number]);

//Recorded in a file
file_put_contents("file.txt", implode("", $file_out));
```

Comment: loading the  entire thing into memory isn't optimal for large files

Comment: Yes, it is true. But in the above question, as I understand, it's about a small amount of data.

Comment: This will print out the 2 desired lines from a new file? Because I'm trying to only use 1 file where the code actively removes the line from the file so only the two lines remain.

Comment: Works great. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: How to do with a large amount of data, a big file ?